# Removing first 'G' character of entire column values in table if it is starting from 'G'

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to remove first 'G' character of full column values of table only if it exist.

I have tried the substr function to remove first char but it will remove the first char even if it is not 'G'. I only wanted to remove first char of entire column values if it is 'G'.

For example in myTable the column values are as follows:

```
G12345
332157
G54337
G54332
534535
```

Expected result is as follows:

```
12345
332157
54337
54332
534535
```

Wanted to write update query to update the entire column value.

Comment: If there are two leading G's, do you still want to remove only one of them?

Comment: Do you want to select from the table or update rows in the table?

Comment: update rows in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace('G12345', 'G', '', 1, 1)
```

If you only want to remove a `'G'` at the beginning of the string, you can use `'^G'` for the pattern.

Based on your data, you can just use `replace()`:

```
select replace('G12345', 'G', '')
```

This removes all `'G'`s.  But your data only seems to have one.

For an `update` you would just include the logic as an update:

```
update t
    set col = replace(col, 'G', '')
    where col like '%G%';
```

Or whichever of the above functions is what you really want to do.

Comment: I wanted to replace entire column value  replace(columnName, 'G', '') from mytable;  I wanted to write update query for my table

Answer (score 1):

You want to update the rows where the value starts with a 'G', so use a `WHERE` clause:

```
update mytable
set value = substr(value, 2)
where value like 'G%';
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to replace **only the first G**, then

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'G12345' from dual union all
  3     select '332157' from dual union all
  4     select '11G222' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7    substr(col, case when substr(col, 1, 1) = 'G' then 2 else 1 end) result
  8  from test;

COL    RESULT
------ ------
G12345 12345
332157 332157
11G222 11G222

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN value LIKE 'G%' THEN SUBSTR( value, 2 ) ELSE value END
         AS value_without_g
FROM   myTable
```

Which, from the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable ( value ) AS
SELECT 'G12345' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '332157' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'G54337' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'G54332' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '534535' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE_WITHOUT_G |
> | :-------------- |
> | 12345           |
> | 332157          |
> | 54337           |
> | 54332           |
> | 534535          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d2bd7ca6eddb2c75b9ab89f34ac2c8d3)*

Comment: I wanted update query to update full column value.